# Patrol not forcing https on 404 pages

Tags: craft3

I've got a site set up with the [Patrol plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/patrol), and it forces the HTTPS and www on most pages fine. I've got the `sslRoutingBaseUrl`, `sslRoutingEnabled`, and `sslRoutingRestrictedUrls` set in my general.php config file (just like in the [github example](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft-plugin-patrol#configure)). It works 99% of the time.

But it doesn't work right for 404s.

Normally, when I go to a page, it automatically changes from http://mysite.com/mypage to https://www.mysite.com/mypage

But when I got to a broken page, http://mysite.com/brokenpageurl, it doesn't redirect.

My 404.twig template lives in the root of the templates directory. So if I go to mysite.com/404, it automatically redirects to https://www.mysite.com/404 - because it's a real page.

But when another page exits to a 404, it doesn't redirect.

I'm wondering if the 'exit to 404' rendering bit happens before patrol gets a chance to do its redirect.

On Craft 3.3.19 and Patrol 3.1.3. But I can reproduce the issue on a couple of different sites.

Edit: I made [a ticket on github](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft-plugin-patrol/issues/21) too.

Comment: I was going to suggest creating an issue on their repo, but it looks like you beat me to it. :) https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft-plugin-patrol/issues/21

Comment: I'd suggest enforcing things like SSL/non-SSL and www./non-www. in your webserver's config rather then via a plugin. [Apache rewrite http to https](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) -- [Nginx rewrite http to https](https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx)

Comment: Seeing no bites here or on my github issue, I put rewrite rules into my .htaccess file.